# Pandas stock fifo calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm try to calculate FIFO on my transaction trades data in pandas.

```
    datetime    symbol  side    price   amount  cost
0   2021-09-19 17:30    SOL/USD buy 157.0950    0.19    29.848050
1   2021-09-20 14:44    SOL/USD buy 142.3100    0.02    2.846200
2   2021-09-20 19:13    SOL/USD buy 135.0575    0.01    1.350575
3   2021-09-21 00:13    SOL/USD buy 128.3400    0.01    1.283400
4   2021-09-21 01:33    SOL/USD sell    138.2550    0.01    1.382550
5   2021-09-22 12:36    SOL/USD sell    129.4450    0.21    27.183450
6   2021-09-22 17:02    SOL/USD buy 142.6825    0.20    28.536500
7   2021-09-22 17:21    SOL/USD sell    141.9175    0.04    5.676700
8   2021-09-22 17:22    SOL/USD buy 141.7600    0.04    5.670400
9   2021-09-22 17:23    SOL/USD sell    141.7825    0.04    5.671300
10  2021-09-22 17:24    SOL/USD buy 141.2950    0.04    5.651800
11  2021-09-22 17:25    SOL/USD sell    141.3800    0.05    7.069000
12  2021-09-22 17:28    SOL/USD buy 141.4375    0.05    7.071875
13  2021-09-22 17:30    SOL/USD sell    141.1275    0.03    4.233825
14  2021-09-22 17:32    SOL/USD buy 142.0850    0.01    1.420850
15  2021-09-22 17:35    SOL/USD buy 142.1575    0.01    1.421575
16  2021-09-22 17:39    SOL/USD sell    142.9525    0.07    10.006675
17  2021-09-22 17:40    SOL/USD buy 142.9025    0.07    10.003175
18  2021-09-22 17:52    SOL/USD sell    144.1125    0.03    4.323375
19  2021-09-22 17:55    SOL/USD buy 143.8725    0.03    4.316175
20  2021-09-22 18:02    SOL/USD sell    144.4950    0.03    4.334850
21  2021-09-22 18:06    SOL/USD buy 147.1300    0.03    4.413900
22  2021-09-22 18:07    SOL/USD sell    146.9125    0.03    4.407375
23  2021-09-22 18:12    SOL/USD buy 149.3650    0.03    4.480950
24  2021-09-22 18:14    SOL/USD sell    150.0600    0.02    3.001200
25  2021-09-22 18:15    SOL/USD sell    149.9400    0.02    2.998800
26  2021-09-22 18:15    SOL/USD buy 149.6225    0.04    5.984900
27  2021-09-22 18:31    SOL/USD sell    148.2325    0.03    4.446975
28  2021-09-22 18:36    SOL/USD buy 148.0575    0.03    4.441725
29  2021-09-22 18:40    SOL/USD sell    147.3600    0.06    8.841600
30  2021-09-22 18:41    SOL/USD buy 147.2825    0.06    8.836950
31  2021-09-22 18:44    SOL/USD sell    146.9650    0.03    4.408950
32  2021-09-22 18:47    SOL/USD buy 144.5800    0.03    4.337400
33  2021-09-22 19:20    SOL/USD sell    147.6925    0.06    8.861550
34  2021-09-26 09:45    SOL/USD sell    133.9000    0.06    8.034000
35  2021-09-26 16:51    SOL/USD buy 138.7000    0.13    18.031000
36  2021-09-26 17:54    SOL/USD buy 136.6550    0.01    1.366550
37  2021-09-27 09:07    SOL/USD sell    142.8500    0.01    1.428500
38  2021-09-27 11:28    SOL/USD sell    146.3950    0.06    8.783700
39  2021-09-27 12:03    SOL/USD buy 147.2575    0.18    26.506350
40  2021-09-27 12:04    SOL/USD sell    146.1375    0.03    4.384125
41  2021-09-27 12:08    SOL/USD buy 146.4575    0.04    5.858300
42  2021-09-29 14:09    SOL/USD sell    137.8800    0.12    16.545600
43  2021-10-03 15:10    SOL/USD sell    174.9900    0.02    3.499800
44  2021-10-03 15:10    SOL/USD sell    174.9900    0.02    3.499800
```

next i groupby side columns on dataframe.
[image]

how can i replace first nan with last sell order and not repeat it.

pandas.fillna('bfill') does not work because it use transaction more than one time.

[image]

Anyone can help me to sharing code to solve my problem or advise me on this?

I need output like this

[image]
Thank You So much.

Comment: What is the expected output for the first 3 lines, please?

Comment: now i edit to add my expected output thank you.